# How can I implement this asynchronous workflow?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await

I'm developing a web application to crawl through pages of a web forum using a function like

```
public IEnumerable<HtmlDocument> GetPages(int pageNumMax = Int32.MaxValue)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= pageNummax; ++i)
    {
        var pagedoc = GetHtmlFromUrl($"http://someforum.com?page={i}"); 
        if(pagedoc == null) // couldn't get; assume page doesn't exist
            yield break;
        else
            yield return pagedoc;
    }
}
```

and I want two wrapping functions

```
public HtmlDocument GetFirstPage()
{
    return GetPages(0).SingleOrDefault();
}

public IEnumerable<HtmlDocument> FullScan()
{
    return GetPages();
}
```

to run as such

- Run `FullScan` every 5 minutes, or if the last `FullScan` isn't done after 5 minutes, run it again as soon as it is done
- Run `GetFirstPage` every 10 seconds, or if there are more than 3 currently running, wait until 1 finishes before running the next one.

Questions:

- Is this possible?
- How would I implement it?
- I chose the number 3 arbitrarily. How do I determine better limit for the number of threads running a `GetFirstPage`?

Comment: Yield always runs synchronous. You can't use this feature in async call. But take a look at async/await or Parallel.Foreach maybe :)

Comment: It seems to me that the asynchrony should start with GetHtmlFromUrl, that is you should make that method asynchronous and work your way up from there using async/await pattern.

Comment: What do threads have to do with it? This program is gated on IO, not number of processors. Why would you have any number of threads other than one?